# Is it possbile to forward ports automatically via ssh from server

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, sshd

Is it possible to forward some ports automatically from the server (define in server sshd_config)?

E.g. any user who connects will have particular forwarding rules regardless if he configured his client properly.

Every page I found needs the user to specify this in his local configuration, which might not be feasible for every user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The server configuration has several options to control what kinds of port forwarding are permitted. But it's the client which decides whether to forward ports or not.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll provide some preconfigure solution for the users.